# How to Sort or Filter imported IMPORTHTML column with Numbers & Text Strings in it?

Tags: arrays, sorting, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm basically importing both Tables from [this](https://santemontreal.qc.ca/en/public/coronavirus-covid-19/) website.

Q1. When I'm importing data via IMPORTHTML and sorting out results, some results are showing as "5 cases or less". It's making it hard to sort it out. I want these to come after 0. How can I make sure of that? 
[image]

Q2. I wish to import only the numbers from the  element. It's basically a whole phrase. How do I only import the last number, in such case, 1,991?
[image]

Here is my [Sample Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18_Dmrd2jCbrDvWnfX-iz4h8LzqBKUj1Cq7UZN_VGlEA/edit#gid=1641564543)

Comment: As for Q2: `REGEXTRACT` could be used to get the number at the end:  `=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML("https://santemontreal.qc.ca/en/public/coronavirus-covid-19/","//div[@id='c36390']/h4[2]"), "[\d,.]+$")` ([screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/ofaKT01.png)). See your test sheet.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT({IMPORTHTML(
 "https://santemontreal.qc.ca/en/public/coronavirus-covid-19/",
 "table", 1), REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://santemontreal.qc.ca/en/public/coronavirus-covid-19/", "table", 1),
 "5 cases or less", 0), "\*", )*1}, 6, 0), 99^99, 2)
```

[image: 0]

not sure if you want 3rd and 4th column too so if you do then change `2` to `4`

---

```
=REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML(
 "https://santemontreal.qc.ca/en/public/coronavirus-covid-19/",
 "//div[@id='c36390']/h4[2]"), "(.*) ", )*1
```

[image: 0]